# Python Recipie book writing and reading to files

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a recipe book in Python that will do the following things:

Create a program that will store the ingredients for a recipe.

The program should ask the user to input:

- the number of people the recipe will serve
- a list of ingredients: item, quantity and units for example flour, 150, grams

The program should store the recipe name, number of people and the list of ingredients with their quantities and units.

The user should be able to retrieve the recipe and have the ingredients recalculated for a different number of people.

The program should ask the user to input the number of people.

The program should output:

- the recipe name
- the new number of people
- the revised quantities with units for this number of people.

My Code:

```
def print_menu():
print('Make a choice.')
print('1. Add a new recipe')
print('2. Search for an existing recipe')
print()

sname=""
i = 0
x = 0
z = 0
ingn = ""
unit = ""
value = ""
ing = []
rname=""
menu_no=0

print_menu()
    while menu_no != 5:
    menu_no = int(input("Choose an option (1-2): "))
       if menu_no == 1:
       rname = str(input("Choose a name for the recipe "))
       i = int(input("How many ingredients do you want? "))
       z = int(input("How many people does this recipie serve? "))
       while x < i:
        x = x+1
        ingn = input("What is the ingredient? ")
        value = int(input("How much of it? No units. "))
        unit = input("What units? ")
        ing.append(ingn)
        ing.append(value)
        ing.append(unit)
        print (ing)
    rname = (rname + ".txt")
    text_file = open(rname, "w")
    text_file.writelines(ing)
```

This is the current code I have so far. If you run the code, everything can e inputted up until text_file.writelines(ing), upon which an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\Year 11 work\Recipe\Morgan Bedford\Recipie.py", line 36, in <module>
    text_file.writelines(ing)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

This is a problem, because as far as I know I need to save these things as what they are (strings, integers), and edit them to change for the amount of people, as well as out putting them.

Any help on why this error occurs and how to fix it would be much appreciated, as well as any advice for the rest of the code.

Comment: The indentation is still messed up.

Comment: At least one of the things in `ing` is an `int` (the `value`). It seems those have to be `str` to write them to file.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking this is a GCSE computing task?  You might want to read this [open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).  Make sure you understand what the error message is telling you.  Think about how you could turn the members of `ing` into the `string` type that `writelines` needs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'fileobject.writelines()' takes any iterable object in the form of strings. In your example, 'value' stores integer :

line28 : *value = int(input("How much of it? No units. "))*

you could confirm this with :
print (type(value)):

So, it needs to be converted to string before passing into writelines().

Change the line32 :

from : *ing.append(value)*
to ***ing.append(str(value))***

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
text_file = open(rname, "w")
for item in ing:
    text_file.writelines(str(item))
```